# Remove context menu entries from battery symbol

Tags: windows-8, taskbar, context-menu

I have some entries in the context menu of my battery icon in the Taskbar Notification Area (TNA):

[image]

This appears, after I right-click the battery icon. Apparently the uninstall routine missed them.

They have no function. When I click them I get a "File not found" error message.

How can I remove them?

Answer (score 0):

The entries are located in the following registry key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\SysTray\BattMeter\ContextMenu

as keys with numeric names. Simply delete the faulty ones. Look at their ItemName Vallue to distinguish between them.

Changes are applied immediately, no reboot needed.